# help needed to fit a new chandlier to a loop system

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image: celing rose]

[image: chandlier]

I need help as I dont know how to connect these 3 blue and 3 brown to this chandelier.  I have tried to look for the answer online but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Blue is neutral and brown is hot for a 240v UK or Aussie or anyone else using the harmonized color code system.   My, those are interesting clear and translucent terminal blocks.  I have only ever seen those used on low voltage systems.  What country is this, anyhow?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a fairly standard UK or similar ceiling rose. Therefore, of the top 3 blues, 2 are loopthrough and the fitting connects to the other. Of the 3 browns, they are also probably loopthrough plus a feed to the switch. Of the bottom two wires, the blue has a brown sheath so I would guess it is a switched return and the fitting connects to that. The earth block (green/yellow) would be connected to the earth on fitting. It doesn't look like it is connected at the moment; because of this, I suspect the white cable leads to a double insulated fitting that doesn't require it.

Your new chandelier appears to have a metal boss / stems, so the
 earth is now required. You shouldn't need the choc block connector, so wire directly to the rose fitting as a direct replacement of what is there. Obviously - you'll need to turn off the lighting circuit breaker and check it's safe before proceeding with a meter. How you fix the cover plate up is up to you.

Comment: What he said. Also, here is link to a helpful internet page on standard wiring for UK ceiling roses: ceilingrosewiring.co.uk/ceiling-rose-wiring-older-cable-colours . In this tutorial they show the "old" UK colors which were red and black. With the new colors, red=brown and black=blue.